# I can not count matching string from another string

Tags: java

```
String s1 = "aabbccaa";
String s2 = "aa";
```

I need to count how many times `s2` repeated in `s1`. I tried split text with no luck. Can someone help?

```
    String s1 ="aabbccaa";
    String s2 = "aa";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
            if(s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your attempts please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. In the comment section, the code is unreadable.

Comment: You want to compare the whole `String`, not single characters. Hint: if you want to write the functionality yourself, you need at least two loops.

Comment: Basically, the output (result) should be 2 since s2 is repeating twice in s1. Is it achievable with 2 for loops?

Comment: Yes it absolutely is, but if you have trouble doing it with two loops, you can use more if this makes it easier for you (why must my answer be at least 15 characters long? Well now I am going to write an answer that is far longer as it has to be just because I am getting annoyed...)

Comment: [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+count+how+many+times+a+string+appears+in+another+string+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS752US752&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR56nj5p_jAhWHHM0KHfbUDjEQrQIoBDAAegQIBBAM) might be helpful.

Comment: that was a funny comment :) Am I getting close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 ="aabbccaassssASaatestaa";
    String s2 = "aa";
    // split the string S1 by  s2 
    String a[] = s1.split(s2); 


    //Output will be 4 - because 'aa' 4 times in s1
    System.out.println(a.length);
}
}

Output - 4
```

In case of overlapping you can use the 'matcher' to get the count of match string in other.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_matcher_replaceall.htm

```
 String s1 ="aaaassssaassaass";
    String s2 = "aa";

   Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile(s2);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1); 
    int i = 0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        i++;
    }
    //Out put will be 4
    System.out.println(i);
```

[Working Demo](http://tpcg.io/I3cBKZ)

Comment: This will not take care of overlapping occurences. E.g. for `s1 = "aaaa"; s2 = "aa";` it will return `2` instead of ´3´

Answer (score 0):

I use Regex. Not sure if this is what you want
Create a parttern from input s2 and match it with s1.
Match will create a list matcher and count it which is the answer.

```
    public int countString(String s1, String s2) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(s2);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);

        int count = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Output is 2

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. You should add an explanation how your code solves the problem.

Comment: That is correct, I have updated my code by using Regex

Answer (score -1):

You can use the indexOf method.

String indexOf(String str) : This method returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring. If it does not occur as a substring, -1 is returned.

Comment: The OP is looking to count the number of occurrences.

Comment: This alone will not do the job. You also need the `substring(...)` method (for skipping one occurence and find the next)

Comment: THANK YOU Shivendra Singh!!!!! You solved it way easier than I thought...